# Building libyuv for pjsip for iPhone for arm64

Tags: ios, iphone, pjsip, arm64, libyuv

I have been trying to build Libyuv for arm64 architecture and then integrate it to PJSIP library. But I am not getting any progress as Pjsip is not able to find the `libyuv.a` framework.

While configuring the Pjsip build, I use following command :

```
ARCH='-arch arm64' ./configure-iphone --with-libyuv=/Users/Mayur/Desktop/pjsip/externals/libyuv/out_ios/Release-iphoneos
```

This is the folder where `libyuv.a` is located.

But, while configuration, this line appears :

```
checking for I420Scale in -lyuv... no
```

Any suggestions on what's wrong here?

References :

1. Building Pjsip for iPhone : https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone
2. Building libyuv : https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/ticket/1776

**UPDATE**

This is how I built `libyuv.a`

1. GYP_DEFINES="OS=ios target_arch=arm64 target_subarch=arm64" GYP_CROSSCOMPILE=1 GYP_GENERATOR_FLAGS="output_dir=out_ios" ./gyp_libyuv -f ninja --depth=. libyuv_test.gyp
2. ninja -j7 -C out_ios/Release-iphoneos libyuv_unittest

This successfully creates the library, but I am not getting a proper way to connect that lib!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that if you use the latest revision for PJSIP and install the `libyuv` framework as described in the question, it just builds perfectly.

Just check out the revision 5128, using the following command :

```
svn checkout -r 5128 http://svn.pjsip.org/repos/pjproject/trunk pjproject
```

It also contains fixes for orientation in iOS!

Answer (score 1):

Use the following script for Building PJSIP Library.

Steps :

1. Copy Script and make .sh file.
2. Copy .sh file in PJSIP Lib folder.
3. Run chmod 777 .sh_filename
4. Run script (e.x ./pjsip_auto_2.6.sh)

---

```
#!/bin/sh

BASE_DIR=$(pwd)

# Create config_site.h file in path
echo "#define PJ_CONFIG_IPHONE 1 
#define PJ_HAS_IPV6 1
#include <pj/config_site_sample.h>" > pjlib/include/pj/config_site.h


# Compile Library and Build For Default iPhone 4 use armv7 architecture
./configure-iphone && make dep && make clean && make


# Build For iPhone 5, use armv7s architecture
ARCH='-arch armv7s' ./configure-iphone && make dep && make clean && make


# Build For iPhone 5s, use arm64 architecture
ARCH='-arch arm64' ./configure-iphone && make dep && make clean && make


# Build For Simulator, use i386 architecture
export DEVPATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer
ARCH="-arch i386" CFLAGS="-O2 -m32 -mios-simulator-version-min=5.0" LDFLAGS="-O2 -m32 -mios-simulator-version-min=5.0" ./configure-iphone
make dep && make clean && make


# Build For Simulator, use x86_64 architecture
export DEVPATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer
ARCH="-arch x86_64" CFLAGS="-O2 -m32 -mios-simulator-version-min=5.0" LDFLAGS="-O2 -m32 -mios-simulator-version-min=5.0" ./configure-iphone
make dep && make clean && make


# Create (arm64,armv7,armv7s,i386, x86_64, unified) Folder
if [ ! -d libs/arm64 ];
then
mkdir -p libs/arm64
echo "arm64 Folder created"
else
echo "arm64 Folder exists"
fi

if [ ! -d libs/armv7 ];
then
mkdir -p libs/armv7
echo "armv7 Folder created"
else
echo "armv7 Folder exists"
fi

if [ ! -d libs/armv7s ];
then
mkdir -p libs/armv7s
echo "armv7s Folder created"
else
echo "armv7s Folder exists"
fi

if [ ! -d libs/i386 ];
then
mkdir -p libs/i386
echo "i386 Folder created"
else
echo "i386 Folder exists"
fi

if [ ! -d libs/x86_64 ];
then
mkdir -p libs/x86_64
echo "x86_64 Folder created"
else
echo "x86_64 Folder exists"
fi

if [ ! -d libs/unified ];
then
mkdir -p libs/unified
echo "unified Folder created"
else
echo "unified Folder exists"
fi


# Copy From pjlib folder to Libs

cp pjlib/lib/*-arm64-apple-darwin_ios.a libs/arm64/
cp pjlib/lib/*-armv7-apple-darwin_ios.a libs/armv7/
cp pjlib/lib/*-armv7s-apple-darwin_ios.a libs/armv7s/
cp pjlib/lib/*-i386-apple-darwin_ios.a libs/i386/
cp pjlib/lib/*-x86_64-apple-darwin_ios.a libs/x86_64/

# Copy From pjlib-util folder to Libs

cp pjlib-util/lib/*-arm64-apple-darwin_ios.a libs/arm64/
cp pjlib-util/lib/*-armv7-apple-darwin_ios.a libs/armv7/
cp pjlib-util/lib/*-armv7s-apple-darwin_ios.a libs/armv7s/
cp pjlib-util/lib/*-i386-apple-darwin_ios.a libs/i386/
cp pjlib-util/lib/*-x86_64-apple-darwin_ios.a libs/x86_64/

# Copy From pjmedia folder to Libs

cp pjmedia/lib/*-arm64-apple-darwin_ios.a libs/arm64/
cp pjmedia/lib/*-armv7-apple-darwin_ios.a libs/armv7/
cp pjmedia/lib/*-armv7s-apple-darwin_ios.a libs/armv7s/
cp pjmedia/lib/*-i386-apple-darwin_ios.a libs/i386/
cp pjmedia/lib/*-x86_64-apple-darwin_ios.a libs/x86_64/

# Copy From pjnath folder to Libs

cp pjnath/lib/*-arm64-apple-darwin_ios.a libs/arm64/
cp pjnath/lib/*-armv7-apple-darwin_ios.a libs/armv7/
cp pjnath/lib/*-armv7s-apple-darwin_ios.a libs/armv7s/
cp pjnath/lib/*-i386-apple-darwin_ios.a libs/i386/
cp pjnath/lib/*-x86_64-apple-darwin_ios.a libs/x86_64/

# Copy From pjsip folder to Libs

cp pjsip/lib/*-arm64-apple-darwin_ios.a libs/arm64/
cp pjsip/lib/*-armv7-apple-darwin_ios.a libs/armv7/
cp pjsip/lib/*-armv7s-apple-darwin_ios.a libs/armv7s/
cp pjsip/lib/*-i386-apple-darwin_ios.a libs/i386/
cp pjsip/lib/*-x86_64-apple-darwin_ios.a libs/x86_64/

# Copy From third_party folder to Libs

cp third_party/lib/*-arm64-apple-darwin_ios.a libs/arm64/
cp third_party/lib/*-armv7-apple-darwin_ios.a libs/armv7/
cp third_party/lib/*-armv7s-apple-darwin_ios.a libs/armv7s/
cp third_party/lib/*-i386-apple-darwin_ios.a libs/i386/
cp third_party/lib/*-x86_64-apple-darwin_ios.a libs/x86_64/


# Rename file name From Created folder

cd $BASE_DIR/libs/arm64/
rename 's/\-arm64\-apple\-darwin_ios//g' *.a

cd $BASE_DIR/libs/armv7/
rename 's/\-armv7\-apple\-darwin_ios//g' *.a

cd $BASE_DIR/libs/armv7s/
rename 's/\-armv7s\-apple\-darwin_ios//g' *.a

cd $BASE_DIR/libs/i386/
rename 's/\-i386\-apple\-darwin_ios//g' *.a

cd $BASE_DIR/libs/x86_64/
rename 's/\-x86_64\-apple\-darwin_ios//g' *.a


cd $BASE_DIR/libs/

# Combine Libs to united folder

export LIB_NAME="libg7221codec.a"
lipo -arch armv7 armv7/$LIB_NAME -arch armv7s armv7s/$LIB_NAME -arch arm64 arm64/$LIB_NAME -arch i386 i386/$LIB_NAME -arch x86_64 x86_64/$LIB_NAME -create -output unified/$LIB_NAME

export LIB_NAME="libgsmcodec.a"
lipo -arch armv7 armv7/$LIB_NAME -arch armv7s armv7s/$LIB_NAME -arch arm64 arm64/$LIB_NAME -arch i386 i386/$LIB_NAME -arch x86_64 x86_64/$LIB_NAME -create -output unified/$LIB_NAME

export LIB_NAME="libilbccodec.a"
lipo -arch armv7 armv7/$LIB_NAME -arch armv7s armv7s/$LIB_NAME -arch arm64 arm64/$LIB_NAME -arch i386 i386/$LIB_NAME -arch x86_64 x86_64/$LIB_NAME -create -output unified/$LIB_NAME

export LIB_NAME="libpj.a"
lipo -arch armv7 armv7/$LIB_NAME -arch armv7s armv7s/$LIB_NAME -arch arm64 arm64/$LIB_NAME -arch i386 i386/$LIB_NAME -arch x86_64 x86_64/$LIB_NAME -create -output unified/$LIB_NAME

export LIB_NAME="libpjlib-util.a"
lipo -arch armv7 armv7/$LIB_NAME -arch armv7s armv7s/$LIB_NAME -arch arm64 arm64/$LIB_NAME -arch i386 i386/$LIB_NAME -arch x86_64 x86_64/$LIB_NAME -create -output unified/$LIB_NAME

export LIB_NAME="libpjmedia-audiodev.a"
lipo -arch armv7 armv7/$LIB_NAME -arch armv7s armv7s/$LIB_NAME -arch arm64 arm64/$LIB_NAME -arch i386 i386/$LIB_NAME -arch x86_64 x86_64/$LIB_NAME -create -output unified/$LIB_NAME

export LIB_NAME="libpjmedia-codec.a"
lipo -arch armv7 armv7/$LIB_NAME -arch armv7s armv7s/$LIB_NAME -arch arm64 arm64/$LIB_NAME -arch i386 i386/$LIB_NAME -arch x86_64 x86_64/$LIB_NAME -create -output unified/$LIB_NAME

export LIB_NAME="libpjmedia-videodev.a"
lipo -arch armv7 armv7/$LIB_NAME -arch armv7s armv7s/$LIB_NAME -arch arm64 arm64/$LIB_NAME -arch i386 i386/$LIB_NAME -arch x86_64 x86_64/$LIB_NAME -create -output unified/$LIB_NAME

export LIB_NAME="libpjmedia.a"
lipo -arch armv7 armv7/$LIB_NAME -arch armv7s armv7s/$LIB_NAME -arch arm64 arm64/$LIB_NAME -arch i386 i386/$LIB_NAME -arch x86_64 x86_64/$LIB_NAME -create -output unified/$LIB_NAME

export LIB_NAME="libpjnath.a"
lipo -arch armv7 armv7/$LIB_NAME -arch armv7s armv7s/$LIB_NAME -arch arm64 arm64/$LIB_NAME -arch i386 i386/$LIB_NAME -arch x86_64 x86_64/$LIB_NAME -create -output unified/$LIB_NAME

export LIB_NAME="libpjsdp.a"
lipo -arch armv7 armv7/$LIB_NAME -arch armv7s armv7s/$LIB_NAME -arch arm64 arm64/$LIB_NAME -arch i386 i386/$LIB_NAME -arch x86_64 x86_64/$LIB_NAME -create -output unified/$LIB_NAME

export LIB_NAME="libpjsip-simple.a"
lipo -arch armv7 armv7/$LIB_NAME -arch armv7s armv7s/$LIB_NAME -arch arm64 arm64/$LIB_NAME -arch i386 i386/$LIB_NAME -arch x86_64 x86_64/$LIB_NAME -create -output unified/$LIB_NAME

export LIB_NAME="libpjsip-ua.a"
lipo -arch armv7 armv7/$LIB_NAME -arch armv7s armv7s/$LIB_NAME -arch arm64 arm64/$LIB_NAME -arch i386 i386/$LIB_NAME -arch x86_64 x86_64/$LIB_NAME -create -output unified/$LIB_NAME

export LIB_NAME="libpjsip.a"
lipo -arch armv7 armv7/$LIB_NAME -arch armv7s armv7s/$LIB_NAME -arch arm64 arm64/$LIB_NAME -arch i386 i386/$LIB_NAME -arch x86_64 x86_64/$LIB_NAME -create -output unified/$LIB_NAME

export LIB_NAME="libpjsua.a"
lipo -arch armv7 armv7/$LIB_NAME -arch armv7s armv7s/$LIB_NAME -arch arm64 arm64/$LIB_NAME -arch i386 i386/$LIB_NAME -arch x86_64 x86_64/$LIB_NAME -create -output unified/$LIB_NAME

export LIB_NAME="libpjsua2.a"
lipo -arch armv7 armv7/$LIB_NAME -arch armv7s armv7s/$LIB_NAME -arch arm64 arm64/$LIB_NAME -arch i386 i386/$LIB_NAME -arch x86_64 x86_64/$LIB_NAME -create -output unified/$LIB_NAME

export LIB_NAME="libresample.a"
lipo -arch armv7 armv7/$LIB_NAME -arch armv7s armv7s/$LIB_NAME -arch arm64 arm64/$LIB_NAME -arch i386 i386/$LIB_NAME -arch x86_64 x86_64/$LIB_NAME -create -output unified/$LIB_NAME

export LIB_NAME="libspeex.a"
lipo -arch armv7 armv7/$LIB_NAME -arch armv7s armv7s/$LIB_NAME -arch arm64 arm64/$LIB_NAME -arch i386 i386/$LIB_NAME -arch x86_64 x86_64/$LIB_NAME -create -output unified/$LIB_NAME

export LIB_NAME="libsrtp.a"
lipo -arch armv7 armv7/$LIB_NAME -arch armv7s armv7s/$LIB_NAME -arch arm64 arm64/$LIB_NAME -arch i386 i386/$LIB_NAME -arch x86_64 x86_64/$LIB_NAME -create -output unified/$LIB_NAME

export LIB_NAME="libyuv.a"
lipo -arch armv7 armv7/$LIB_NAME -arch armv7s armv7s/$LIB_NAME -arch arm64 arm64/$LIB_NAME -arch i386 i386/$LIB_NAME -arch x86_64 x86_64/$LIB_NAME -create -output unified/$LIB_NAME

export LIB_NAME="libwebrtc.a"
lipo -arch armv7 armv7/$LIB_NAME -arch armv7s armv7s/$LIB_NAME -arch arm64 arm64/$LIB_NAME -arch i386 i386/$LIB_NAME -arch x86_64 x86_64/$LIB_NAME -create -output unified/$LIB_NAME



echo 'Congratulation you have built PJSIP Library successfully'
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Since PJSIP 2.5.5, libyuv is included in the PJSIP package and configure script param --with-libyuv is removed, check ticket #1937 for more info.

https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone